# Объединить таблицы

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица df_1

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2011,2012,2013,2014], 'Завод':['kamaz','disel','nissan','bmw'],
                     'AA':[11,212,213,204],'AB':[121,2212,2313,204]})
```

Есть таблица df_2

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2011,2012,2013,2014], 'kamaz':[5,0,0,1],'disel':[1,2,3,4],'nissan':[1,1,1,1],'bmw':[11,11,11,12]})
```

Я хочу получить такую таблицу, тут показан пример только для Камаза

```
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2011], 'AA_kamaz':[5*11],'AB_kamaz':[5*121]})
```

Суть таблицы 3. Из таблицы 2 по каждому столбцу найди аналог в таблице 1, учитывая год.  Параметры  АА и АВ  умножить  на значения  столбца  таблицы 1. Пытался merge, транспонировать, но увы не получается. Спасибо

Comment: Тут скорее какой-нибудь `pivot` нужен, но я так сходу не могу сообразить.

Comment: Тоже пытаюсь не выходит, уже сомневаюсь можно ли так

Comment: не совсем понятно почему в результате присутствует только `kamaz`? Куда делись остальные значения?

Comment: MaxU, это просто обрезанный пример, все остальные параметры идут аналогично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
x = (df_2
     .set_index("year")
     .stack()
     .reset_index()
     .rename(columns={"level_1":"Завод", 0:"val"}))
res = (df_1
       .merge(x)
       .eval("AA = AA * val \n AB = AB * val")
       .drop(columns="val")
       .pivot_table(index="year", columns="Завод", fill_value=0))
```

результат:

```
In [32]: res
Out[32]:
         AA                       AB
Завод   bmw disel kamaz nissan   bmw disel kamaz nissan
year
2011      0     0    55      0     0     0   605      0
2012      0   424     0      0     0  4424     0      0
2013      0     0     0    213     0     0     0   2313
2014   2448     0     0      0  2448     0     0      0
```

если не нужны многоэтажные имена столбцов - можно сделать так:

```
res.columns = res.columns.map("_".join)
```

результат:

```
In [36]: res
Out[36]:
      AA_bmw  AA_disel  AA_kamaz  AA_nissan  AB_bmw  AB_disel  AB_kamaz  AB_nissan
year
2011       0         0        55          0       0         0       605          0
2012       0       424         0          0       0      4424         0          0
2013       0         0         0        213       0         0         0       2313
2014    2448         0         0          0    2448         0         0          0
```